# jQuery autocomplete not displaying results in wordpress subsections

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, autocomplete

I am using the jQuery autocomplete on a site that I am building. It works perfectly everywhere but, in a section of the site where I am using wordpress, the results aren't displayed.

The weirdest part is that in the home of that section, it works, but when I go to a subsection or an article, it doesn't.

This is the home of the wordpress section, the autocomplete search is top left:
http://www.metagame.gg/news/

This is a subsection where it is not working: 
http://www.metagame.gg/news/category/opinion/

I have been trying to figure out what is happening, but I couldn't fix it.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 5 errors which is most probably the reason your JavaScript not working

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is
>   installed, version 1.4.0
>   http://www.metagame.gg/news/category/js/jquery.js Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://www.metagame.gg/news/category/js/jquery-ui.js Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   www.metagame.gg/:406 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
>   http://www.metagame.gg/news/category/opinion/style.css Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

mainly there is 2 missing js files (http://www.metagame.gg/news/category/js/jquery.js & http://www.metagame.gg/news/category/js/jquery-ui.js) and a missing CSS http://www.metagame.gg/news/category/opinion/style.css

**further investigation:**

you're using a relative path for the jQuery and jQuery-UI which explains why on homepage you can find root/js/jquery.js but not in root/news/category/js/jquery.js. 
you need to reference root/js/jquery.js from all other pages as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that asap

Comment: To be relative to the root directory, just start the URI with a /
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
<script src="/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>